# Open App From Widget IOS with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How I can open my App from the Today Widget with Swift ?
I just want to pressed the Widget and than i would like to open my App.
I got right now a button on my whole view the button is clear.
But that don't work for me:(
I need Help:)

```
@IBAction func launchApp(sender: AnyObject) {
   var url: NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString("AffordItLauncher://")
   self.extensionContext?.openURL(url, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: **Swift 5.0** let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "AffordItLauncher://")! 
            self.extensionContext?.open(url as URL, completionHandler: nil)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your info.plist you need to add the following:

[image]

And make sure that your app name is the same as the one in your url. In your case, it should be `AffordItLauncher`

Answer (score 0):

row in info.plist seems not needed on iOS17